# React.js using form input in another component

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

So I'm learning about how to use form input across my React app projects.
I'm not really sure how to do it, props dosen't really seem to cut it.
So if I have two components, one with a form, and another that I just want to show the input.
I dont want to render the two components at once but rather wish to redirect the user to another view where the input is shown.
Below is the code for the simple form.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Second from '../view/second/Second';

    const Form = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [namn, setNamn] = useState('');
    const [personNr, setPersonNr] = useState('');
    const [datum, setDatum] = useState('');
    const [planbok, setPlanbok] = useState('');

    
    return (

        <div>
            <form>
                <div>
                <input type="text" id="namnField" required value={namn} 
    onChange={(n) => setNamn(n.target.value)} placeholder='Namn'></input>
                </div>
                <div>
                <input type="text" id="personNrField" required value={personNr} 
    onChange={(pn) => setPersonNr(pn.target.value)} placeholder='Personnr'></input>
                </div>
                <div>
                <input type="text" id="datumField" required value={datum} 
    onChange={(d) => setDatum(d.target.value)} placeholder='Datum'></input>
                </div>
                <div>
                <input type="text" id="planbokField" required value={planbok} 
    onChange={(p)=>setPlanbok(p.target.value)} placeholder='Plånbokadress'></input>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="inputForm"onSubmit {navigate('/second')}>Enter</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Form
```

And here is the component that I want to show the form input:

```
import React from 'react'
import Form from '../../form/Form'

const Second = ({namn, datum, personNr, planbok}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{namn}, {datum}, {personNr}, {planbok}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Second
```

As you see I've tried to use props, this dosen't work.
Sure I can render the component called  in the  component and I can populate  with the form input.
But this is not what I wish to achive, I want the variables from the form input to be shown when I render  in a different view.

How would I achive this, should I use Ajax, the hook useContext? Is there some other way that is better to handle this type of situation?
Thanks in advance for your time.
Regards / Svante.

Comment: I would move the `useState` up one level, and pass `setNamn` etc down to the `Form` (as props) and pass `namn` etc down to the `Second` as props.

Comment: Gonna try that! thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

Solved this problem with useContext.
Used the principles in this youtube video on the subject:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhMKvyLRWo0&t=342s

I think it might be a better practice to do as MrPickles wrote as an answer to my first post.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: In this case if you are a newbie as me I think it is best if you follow the whole video through. :)

Comment: I have to disagree, sorry. This is from the SO guideline, please read [How To Answer Well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I'll give it a read and edit my answer accordingly. :)